# How to fix ImportError:No module named urls?

Tags: python, django

all I am trying to run a Django application and came across and error that says: **ImportError:No module name urls**.

Here is the Traceback that I got:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py",
>   line 85, in run
>       self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py",
>   line 64, in **call**
>       return self.application(environ, start_response)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line
>   168, in **call**
>       self.load_middleware()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line
>   46, in load_middleware
>       mw_instance = mw_class()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line
>   23, in **init**
>       for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line
>   367, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line
>   361, in urlconf_module
>       self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "/Users/edwardkeselman/Desktop/Work/Crowdview/crowdview/urls.py", line
>   20, in 
>       url(r'^analysis/', include('data_analysis.urls')),   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/**init**.py", line
>   28, in include
>       urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "/Users/edwardkeselman/Desktop/Work/Crowdview/data_analysis/urls.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from data_analysis import views   File "/Users/edwardkeselman/Desktop/Work/Crowdview/data_analysis/views.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from rest_framework.decorators import api_view   File "/Users/edwardkeselman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from rest_framework.views import APIView   File "/Users/edwardkeselman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from rest_framework import exceptions, status   File "/Users/edwardkeselman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/exceptions.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       from rest_framework.compat import unicode_to_repr   File "/Users/edwardkeselman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/compat.py",
>   line 21, in 
>       from django.urls import (  # noqa ImportError: No module named urls

Here is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django import template
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('coverage.urls')), 
    url(r'fr/', include('coverage.urls')),
    url(r'en/', include('coverage.urls')),
    url(r'ru/', include('coverage.urls')),
    url(r'zh/', include('coverage.urls')),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^demo/', include('coverage.urls')),
    url(r'^ru/demo/', include('coverage.urls')),
    url(r'^zh/demo/', include('coverage.urls')),
    url(r'^fr/demo/', include('coverage.urls')),
    url(r'^en/demo/', include('coverage.urls')),
    url(r'^analysis/', include('data_analysis.urls')),
    url(r'^telcel_stats/', include('general_stats.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', include('coverage.urls')),
)

template.add_to_builtins('django.templatetags.i18n')
```

How can I fix this problem?

**Edit:**
After trying the suggested answer by Krishna Choudhary, my Traceback looks like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py",
>   line 85, in run
>       self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py",
>   line 64, in **call**
>       return self.application(environ, start_response)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line
>   168, in **call**
>       self.load_middleware()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line
>   46, in load_middleware
>       mw_instance = mw_class()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line
>   23, in **init**
>       for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line
>   367, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line
>   361, in urlconf_module
>       self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name) ImportError: No module named urls

Comment: Which django version is this?

Comment: I use django 1.7 (I know it's old), it's a project that I was given by someone who was working before me.

Comment: It's an issue with Django Rest Framework, [this guy](https://www.queryoverflow.gdn/query/importerror-no-module-named-urls-on-django-rest-framework-tutorial-1-27_51053846.html) has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my project root ... django complained that it couldn't find the module mysite.urls.

Turns out my ROOT_URLCONF variable in settings.py, which was set up using the default values, was set incorrect. Instead of "mysite.urls", it should have been simply "urls"

I changed it, and voila, it worked.

Comment: Thanks, though it didn't solve my problem completely, it shorted my Traceback in half. Unfortunately, it still says "ImportError: No module named urls". Do by any chance have any other suggestion that might work?